# Android: App crashing after button clicked

Tags: java, android

So, right now im working on a parking app. I want to make a dropdown menu for the vehicle type in the compound ticket subsystem. i can run the app smoothly, but when i click the button that will go to the compound ticket class, the app will crash.

**Here is my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserName"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        android:hint="Vehicle No"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/autoComplete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.915" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        android:hint="Type of Vehicle"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/placeoffence"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.979" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/placeoffence"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        android:hint="Place of Offence"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/regBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.755" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/regBtn"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.891" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="185dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
        android:text="Enter \nTraffic Ticket"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.182"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.845" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv6"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/light"
        android:text="Please complete the traffic ticket details for students who violate the rules and laws at UTM."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etUserName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.395"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my Compound Ticket class:**

```
package com.example.depark.police;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.depark.R;

public class CompoundTicket extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] vehicle =  {"Proton","Perodua","Honda","Yamaha"};
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTxt;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compound_ticket);

        autoCompleteTxt = findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);

        adapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_type_of_vehicle,vehicle);
        autoCompleteTxt.setAdapter(adapterItems);

        autoCompleteTxt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item: "+item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My home fragment:**

```
package com.example.depark.police;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.depark.HomeViewModel;
import com.example.depark.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PoliceHomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ImageView img;
    private Button b1;
    private CardView parkingCard, receiptCard, feeCard, valetCard;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.police_home_fragment, container, false);

        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        img = root.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        b1 = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);


        // defining cards
        parkingCard = root.findViewById(R.id.eparking_card);
        receiptCard = root.findViewById(R.id.receipt_card);
        feeCard = root.findViewById(R.id.fee_card);
        valetCard = root.findViewById(R.id.valet_card);

        // add click listener to the cards
        parkingCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        receiptCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        feeCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        valetCard.setOnClickListener(this);

        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).

                child("Images/Profile Pic").

                getDownloadUrl().

                addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess (Uri uri){
                        Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img);
                    }
                });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.eparking_card : i = new Intent (getActivity(), CompoundTicket.class); startActivity(i); break;
           // case R.id.receipt_card : i = new Intent (getActivity(), PaymentListFragment.class); startActivity(i); break;
            //case R.id.fee_card : i = new Intent (getActivity(), StudentListFragment.class); startActivity(i); break;
            //case R.id.valet_card : i = new Intent (getActivity(), ValetListFragment.class); startActivity(i); break;
            default:break;
        }

    }
}
```

**the crash log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.depark, PID: 30834
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.depark/com.example.depark.police.CompoundTicket}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2197)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1839)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5471)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:712)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5429)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:693)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5927)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:830)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:279)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:167)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1445)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1433)
at com.example.depark.police.PoliceHomeFragment.onClick(PoliceHomeFragment.java:92)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: class CompoundTicket method onItemClick, you may want verify that parent != null &   onItemClick has a toString(),  see this doc on how to debug android apps 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Comment: i replaced the parent with AdapterView but still crashed


`@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) { 
String vehicle = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item: "+ vehicle,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

});`

Comment: Adding the crash log might make things clearer for us to inspect. Can you add it please?

Comment: Please show the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The crash states that you might have not declared it over there

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED! adding the CompoundTicket activity class to the AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".police.CompoundTicket" />
```